# ASP.NET MVC - Get database data depending user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm fairly new to the MVC and database stuff.

What I need to do is retrieve data depending on a user's role. I can get all the data from the table below but I need to only show specific data.

```
tableId      roleId        data1        data2        data3
  1            1         some data    some data    some data
  2            1         some data    some data    some data 
  3            1         some data    some data    some data
  4            2         some data    some data    some data 
  5            2         some data    some data    some data
  6            3         some data    some data    some data
```

So if a user is logged in and assigned a role, how would I fetch data from the table for that role?
If I am assigned roleId 1, I should only see data from the table with roleId = 1.

I'm still learning and this would be awesome help.

THANKS!

My Code:

Controller

```
    private projectEntities db = new projectEntities();

    // GET: /Assessment/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View(db.Scales.ToList());
        var data = new ModelServices().GetScale();
        return View(data);


    }
```

Model

```
public class ModelServices : IDisposable
{
    private readonly projectEntities entities = new projectEntities();
    public IEnumerable GetScale()
    {
        return entities.Scales.ToList();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        entities.Dispose();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.Scale>
@{
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);   
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

Comment: "I can get all the data from the table below but I need to only show specific data." How? Are you using a SQL query? LINQ?

Comment: you can always use returnedDataSet.Where(c => c.roleId == 1); to return the rows with roleId = 1, where returnedDataSet is the "dall the data from the table" you retrieved.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Using Linq.

Comment: @user3606394: Can you provide the code snippet to show how you're getting that table's data in the first place? That makes it easier for people to give you a code sample to show how to do what you want.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'll update my question now

Comment: var data = new ModelServices().GetScale();  return View(data.where(c => c.roleId == roleIdINeed)); // here roleIdINeed is the role id you want to filter by

Comment: If your view's model is type `IEnumerable<project.Models.Scale>` then why does your service method only return type `IEnumerable`?  The service should be returning the same generic type as your view uses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new services method like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Scale> GetScalesWithRole(int roleId)
{
    return entities.Scales.Where(s => s.RoleId == roleId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is this the common and most recommended practice? It's simple and straight forward, but I was wondering if there's anything else just better.

Comment: @carloswm85: It's a pretty common practice, but there are other options. For example, some people like to have a generic IRepository that returns an `IQueryable<Scale>` and allow the controller to apply the `Where` clause. Each practice has pros and cons. To decide whether a given pattern is better, I'd have to understand more context, and what criteria should be used when defining "better." If in doubt, I'd say start with something simple like this, and pay attention when you start noticing pain points to decide if you need to adjust it.